# How to plot a line graph for very huge data file?

Tags: data-visualization, large-data

How to plot a graph for very huge data. I am data sets containing minimum of 300000 counts. I need to plot a graph.  Is there any special package for it. Also, I need to insert secondary axis for the same. I know this is a time series graph and how to draw this graph, Just for example sake I am attaching this. I need to plot graphs likes this for huge data.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "line graph"? If you are talking about regression line than you want to plot a straight line -- this is simple no matter of sample size. If you are talking about something else than please edit your question to clarify it (e.g. provide example of such plot).

Comment: Its not a regression lines. Its just a graph for two different series.

Comment: Please provide example as "a graph for two different series" could be almost any graph.

Comment: I think VISHU is looking for the term ["run-sequence"](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/4plot.htm) or ["overlay chart"](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Overlay_Plots.shtml).  If that is the case then I am not entirely clear whether "how to do x with software" is on-topic.

Comment: Try asking this on stack overflow...this is a software question.

Comment: It is exploratory statistics XD it can be done with R easily, I plotted 1 million of points once, it took a while, but worked. http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/line.html

Comment: What is the problem with plotting this data? You can make such plot as above using any software.

Comment: Options could include uniform sub-sampling (if you know there are 1000 points in a single pixel, then you only need one of them to make the plot), overlaping them in bins (hexplot), non-uniform sub-sampling (like bootstrap), and others.  Limits on "others" would be determined by end use.  What do you want to do with the plot once you have it?

Comment: @Tim I know it can be plot using excel itself, but the when I select the data, system is getting hanged. So, I am trying in R. If I plot it using plot() it looks very clumsy. No one can identify even the line.

Comment: @EngrStudent I just want to look the trend graphically. I think your point using uniform sub sampling could help me. How to use it. Can you pls share code for the same.

Answer (score 2):

From what you say in your comment

> If I plot it using plot() it looks very clumsy. No one can identify
>   even the line.

I guess that what you are looking for is smoothing. With large time-series data some local fluctuations may be less important that longer-term fluctuations and so we may want to smooth-out the local ones. There are different algorithms that can help in here, e.g. [LOWESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression). What you need to consider is that the more you smooth your data, more information is lost, but it may improve readability of your plot.

[image]